# Remove column headers from expandable rows in ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have an expandable table. I want to remove the Column headers for the expandable rows only in the table. I tried adding `showHeader : false` to the `subGridOptions`, but this still displays them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `enableExpandableRowHeader: false` in your main `.gridOptions{}`

[GridOptions documentation](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.expandable.api:GridOptions).

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but no luck. Could it have to do with my version?

Comment: Possibly. `options.enableExpandableRowHeader` used to be `options.expandable.enableExpandableRowHeader` so you could try that.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue and I resolved it by adding the below CSS.

```
.expandableRow .ui-grid-header {
    display: none;
}
```